# Permission to call insertImage in a Sheets AppScript function

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts, permissions

I'm running into a problem when trying to insert a ColumnChart into a Google Sheet document as an image via an AppsScript.  The error is:

> Exception: You do not have permission to call insertImage (line 597).

Here is my Code.gs:

```
function testChart() {
  var data = Charts.newDataTable()
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Year")
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Sales")
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Expenses")
    .addRow(["2020", 1000, 500])
    .addRow(["2021", 2000, 1000])
    .addRow(["2022", 4000, 2000])
    .build();

  var chart = Charts.newColumnChart()
    .setTitle('Sales & Expenses')
    .setXAxisTitle('Year')
    .setYAxisTitle('Amount (USD)')
    .setDimensions(600, 500)
    .setDataTable(data)
    .build();

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().insertImage(chart.getAs('image/png'), 1, 1);
}
```

And here is my appsscript.json:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Chicago",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly"
  ]
}
```

Is there something here I'm missing?

Comment: About `Exception: You do not have permission to call insertImage (line 597).`, how did you run your script `testChart()`?

Comment: Yes.  I would type `=testChart()` into a cell to run the code.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `Yes. I would type =testChart() into a cell to run the code.`, if you are using `testChart()` as a custom function, I think that the reason of your current issue of `Exception: You do not have permission to call insertImage (line 597).` is due to this. In this case, I would like to recommend to run your script by other method except for the custom function.

Comment: I need to build charts within my spreadsheet from a custom function call…is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I need to build charts within my spreadsheet from a custom function call…is there a better way to do this?`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, your script cannot be used with the custom function because of the current specification of the custom function. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Apps Script [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) cannot call services that require authorization. As Tanaike suggested in the comments, you will have to call the function through some other means, such as a [button](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets), a [custom menu item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus), a [sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars) or a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).

See [Custom function supported services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services).